# Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '14' of nodejs. This build image has the following versions: 10, 12

Tags: node.js, lambda, build, aws-codebuild

I have updated node version from 12 to 14 for a github project where I have to update the node version from 12 to 14 and then deploy it to aws, but it is giving this error: Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '14' of nodejs. This build image has the following versions: 10, 12. I am not understanding why I am getting this error.

in the aws codebuild-details
image:  aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0
enviorment: LInux

Thanks in advance

I wanted to try image for nodejs 14 which is aws/codebuild/standard:5.0, but this change will get us around the issue in CodeBuild, but I think there might be some unintended side effects. It looks like lambda is run on Amazon Linux, so I don't think it makes sense to package the apollo-server lambda on a ubuntu image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since apparently there is no CodeBuild image for Amazon Linux with NodeJS 14 as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html there are the following options:

- Consider using different NodeJS version as for example there are Amazon Linux images for 16 and 18.
- Use Ubuntu image. It shouldn't matter much as long as NodeJS version is the same.
- Use custom image, e.g. build one yourself. Docker files for standard images are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

Image can be selected by editing the environment of the code build project.

Answer (score 0):

solution is easy when you get message during your test phase on aws codebuild. any message like:

> YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '14' of nodejs. This build image has the following versions: 10, 12.

Solution: go into your `buildspec.yml` file and edit :

```yaml
phases: 
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
```

Change the: `runtime-versions:` nodejs from 10, 12 to version 14 and save it. Then delete the build project and recreate the build and start build. It will work!

Thanks

Comment: I changed in the `buildspec.yml` and getting the same error